# Load all items in magento ui listing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

Currently the items are showing by default 20 per page. Is there a way to load all items?

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel. Go to

> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog

Set **"Products per Page on Grid Default Value"** to the value that you wanted on product list.

Or if products count is too high, I recommend you use some **ajax pagination**. So that user will not suffer slow page load

Comment: Well I don't want it to apply for products. I created a separate listing for my table and i want it to apply for only that.

Comment: Can you share your code here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
I just need to remove

```
<paging name="listing_paging"/>
```